# Show the two given groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to show that the group $G$ of $n$ $nth$ roots of unity are isomorphic to the group $(\{0,1,2,...\},+_n)$

I have defined my $f:G'\rightarrow G$ as $$ f(a)=e^{ 2\pi ai/ n},\; \forall a\in G'$$

I can show that $f$ is bijective. But how do i show that the composition is preserved by $f$ ?

$\forall a,b\in G'$

$f(a+_nb)=e^{2\pi i(a+_nb)/n}$

How does the right hand side work out to be $f(a)f(b)$ ??

Comment: Start by defining $F\colon \mathbb{Z} \to G$, and show that it factors through $G'$.

Comment: i can show that $f:Z\rightarrow G$ is isomorphic. What do i do after that?

Comment: You have a surjective homomorphism $F\colon \mathbb{Z}\to G;\; F(k) = \left(e^{2\pi i/n}\right)^k$. What is its kernel?

Comment: @DanielFischer kernel of $f$ would be all $k\in Z$ that maps to $1$ in $G$

Comment: i didn't understand when you said - "show that it factors through $G'$ " ? @DanielFischer

Comment: By the $k$-th isomorphism theorem, the surjective homomorphism $F$ induces an isomorphism $\tilde{F} \colon \mathbb{Z}/\ker F \to G$. Now, what is $\mathbb{Z}/\ker F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand side works out to be $$f(a+_nb)={\large e^{\large 2\pi i(a+_nb) \over n} = e^{\large \frac{2\pi i a}n + {\frac{\large 2\pi i b}n}} = e^{\large\frac {2\pi i a}n} \cdot e^{\large\frac{2 \pi i b}n}}= f(a)(b)$$

Comment: i didnt get the 3rd and 4th equality. how did $+_n$ became $+$ and came down ? and later it became $\dot$ ??

Comment: I formatted incorrectly. Recall that $e^{x + y} = e^x \cdot e^y$

Comment: $+_n$ doesnt make a difference ? why ?

Comment: Give it a little more thought...Try it with some concrete examples...I'll let you think about it a little while, but will follow up as needed!

Comment: $a+_nb$ basically means a remained when $a+b$ is divided by $n$, so this probably ensures that the group $g$ remains closed.

Comment: Yes, you're thinking in the right direction...

Comment: but then why will $a+_nb=a+b$, until $a+b<n$ , so are we writing it like that because $a+_nb=r<n$ but that would mean that the two will always be equal, which is not so?

Comment: $a +_n b = (a + b)\pmod n \neq a + b$, but $$e^{\frac {i\pi (a+_n b)}{n}}$$ we *are* dividing by $n$, so $$e^{\frac {i\pi (a+_n b)}{n}} = e^{\frac {i\pi a}n + \frac {i\pi b}n} = \cdots...$$

Comment: okie, as $a<n$ and $b<n$, it won't matter if we write this way. Thanks !

Comment: Also, recall that the $nth$ roots of union form a cyclic group. E.g., if n = 4, $$\large e^{\frac {2\pi i(1)}n} = e^{\frac{2\pi i(5)}{4}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i (9)}4} =\cdots$$